# test automation with Xcode for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, automation

I want to use Xcode for test automation. Please help me how can I use? Likewise we use selenium driver in Microsoft visual studio, similarly what’s the procedure for creating test automation for ios app.
Alike we write scenarios and its implementation in MS Visual Studio using Spec flow. I want to do same for iPhone. Need help.
I have googled but I’m still confused what exactly it would need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know 3 framework to test automation for you:

1. KIF: It's write by Objective-C. And easily to use if you familiar with Objective-C language.
2. Frank: It's write by Ruby. I haven't use it much, but I have try and it have less gestures.
3. UI Automation: It's simple, easy and integrate with XCode. And use Javascript to write. If you write a simple testcase, you don't need code, it will record your touch automatically.

Comment: just to be complete: there is calabash too.